# multicast forward action in wireless access point(SOHO Router)

Tags: wireless-networking, router, port-forwarding

I am digging `802.11 multicast forward action in wireless Access Point`, now I have drawed the following conclusions:

- multicast from ethernet port can be forwarded by virtual bridge to wireless port such as `wlan0`.
- multicast from wireless port can be be forwarded by **software layer**(by printing data in driver to make sure) to wireless port.
- 802.11 multicast forward is only sent once to every client in multicast rate 1Mbps with no ACK protection, unless some wireless device set it to higher rate or unicast to every wireless STA.

What I want to know is that **will the multicast packets sent from LAN be reflected back to the same LAN port?**

I have investiged this phenomenon by sending multicast packets from windows PC to wireless channel and ethernet port. The result shows:

1. I can see the original data and a copy of data in wireless channel, which means AP forwards the packet.
2. Only one copy data is shown up in wireshark when I am capturing the data on WLAN interface. I know wireshark only captures 802.3 data when the wireless interface is not set to monitor mode.

So the result may not be accuarate when I test multicast on the ethernet port.

If LAN packets are relected back, will it waste bandwidth?

Answer (score 1):

No, repeaters (hubs) and bridges (switches) cannot forward any packet (multicast *or* unicast) back onto the interface it was received on, because it would cause an infinite packet storm.